# Como calcular la sumatoria de minutos en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, programación-móvil

perdonen la inexperiencia ya que soy nuevo, quisiera saber como calculo los minutos mejor dicho sumarlos para que me de una hora de salida. Lo que pasa es que quiero realizar un ejercicio de los ingresos de pacientes en consultas, por ende nos están pidiendo cuanto se demora los pacientes con cada medico, ingresando primero la hora ingreso a la consulta y luego sumar los minutos con que cada paciente se demora con el medico, por ejemplo, cuanto me demoro, con un psicologo, con un dermatologo, con uno de medicina general, etc y entregar el resultado total como hora de salida.

por ejemplo:

```
     package com.example.asus.crudaplicacion;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class IngresarDatos extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6;
    Button bt1;
    TextView t1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingresar_datos);
        e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtHora);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtPsicologo);
        e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTrabajador);
        e4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtMedico);
        e5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTraumatologo);
        e6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtOtro);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.hora);
        bt1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSumar);
        ....................................

    }
}
```

Aquí tengo el código de configuración, pero después no se que colocar, perdonen la ignorancia es que soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Agrega más información a tu pregunta por favor, en este caso sería bueno definieras que formato estas usando.

Comment: Es que lo que pasa es que no se en que momento tengo que aplicar la sumatoria

Comment: si quieres calcular o hacer un conteo por segundos minutos o horas puedes utilizar la función `sleep()`, y pasarle por parámetros el tiempo, ya lo demás es lógica ;) espero haberte ayudado te doy un consejo, recibe la hora con el `simpleformat()` y lo que haces es un conteo partir de la hora que recibiste y eso se lo sumas o incluso con el solo sleep puedes decir el tiempo que se demoro y no tendrías que usar la función `simpleformat()` todo es cuestión de gustos, te recomiendo que no sea por segudos, hazlo en minutos Suerte! tu puedes!

Comment: usas timepicker o edittext para ingresar los datos(hora, minutos)?